# Protractor / Web Driver : Detect when Class is added to Element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Here is the code for the button. Basically when the button is clicked, it turns blue

```
 <button id="testbutton" type="button" ng-class="selected('test')" ng-click="isMultiple('test')">test</button>
```

In the Browser it basically goes from

```
class = btn btn-block btn-lg ts-btn-default
```

To

```
class = btn btn-block btn-lg ts-btn-blue
```

I have an var for the original element already. How do I get protractor to detect the **ts-btn-blue** being put in? Should I just make another element with the different class and do an

> isdiplayed()

for that one or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for class present after the click:

```
expect(yourElm.getAttribute('class')).toContain('ts-btn-blue');
```

If you encounter timing issues, like your tests failing because the `expect()` runs before the html actually gets to the DOM, you may find useful what i'm actually using below.

```
expect(yourElm).toHaveClass('ts-btn-blue');
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/94284ec0ac3e8a590507) a Jasmine 1.3.x custom `toHaveClass` matcher with negation `.not` support plus wait up to 5 seconds (or whatever you specify).

[Find the full custom matcher to be added on your onPrepare block in this gist](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/94284ec0ac3e8a590507)

#### Sample usage:

```
it('test the class finder custom matcher', function() {
    // These guys should pass OK given your user input
    // element starts with an ng-invalid class:
    expect($('#user_name')).toHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toHaveClass('ZZZ');
    expect($('#user_name')).toNotHaveClass('ZZZ');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toNotHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    // These guys should each fail:
    expect($('#user_name')).toHaveClass('ZZZ');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    expect($('#user_name')).toNotHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toNotHaveClass('ZZZ');
});
```

*UPDATE*

This will only work on ElementFinders. Will work on WebElements once [this jasminewd PR #9](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/pull/9) gets merged.